# Prototype plugin for expanding table rows?

Tags: jquery, plugins, row, prototypejs

jQuery has a plugin called jExpand for expanding table rows. Does Prototype have an equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

The source of jExpand is so small I just went ahead and translated it for you.

```
Element.addMethods(
    'TABLE',
    {
        addJExpand : function(elem){
            elem = $(elem);
            elem.select('tr:nth-child(even)').each(function(child){child.addClassName('odd')});
            elem.select('tr:nth-child(odd)').each(Element.hide);
            elem.down('tr').show();
            elem.select('tr:nth-child(even)').each(
                function(child){
                    child.observe('click', 
                        function(){
                            child.next().toggle();
                        }
                    );
                }   
            );
        }
    }
);
```

Just call it using `table.addJExpand()`, where `table` is your prototype-extended variable. You can also use `Element.addJExpand` for times when you're using `.each`.

You're welcome.